# Replacing a motion in operator mode

Tags: vim

I'm trying to alter the `ge` motion's functionality when it's used with an operator. Instead of it operating on the last character of the target word, I'd like it to work exclusively only *until* the target word's last character similarly to `w`.

Example:

```
foo bar
     ^
```

Should  lead to 
`fooar` instead of `foar` when I use `dge` with the cursor at ^

I don't know anything about Vimscript and I'm pretty much relying on `exe` now. This quick attempt I wrote seems to be full of errors. The variables don't seem to be working right at all.

My leading idea is to escape when ge is typed in operator mode and call the function with hopefully the right arguments. Then set a mark on the starting position, move to the left one column (to ensure that it would work with repeated movements, even though this is operator mode only), move the set amount of `ge`s and then move one column right (my main goal here) and delete till the set mark.

If anybody could point out the errors I've made, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
function! FixGE(count, operator)
    exe 'normal m['
    exe 'normal h'
    exe count.'normal ge'
    exe 'normal l'
    exe operator.'normal `['
endfunction
onoremap ge <esc>:call FixGE(v:prevcount, v:operator)<cr>
```

Comment: I understand. I've changed the comment in a answer, with an alternative to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little closer (untested):

```
function! FixGE(count, operator)
    exe 'normal m['
    exe 'normal h'
    exe 'normal ' . a:count . 'ge'
    exe 'normal l'
    exe 'normal ' . a:operator . '`['
endfunction
onoremap ge <esc>:call FixGE(v:prevcount, v:operator)<cr>
```

Function arguments have to use the `:a` prefix (or sigil, I think).  I know that `count` is a reserved variable:  `:let count = 7` gives an error.  I think it is OK to use it as a function argument, though.

I have also put `:normal` at the beginning of two lines, instead of in the middle.

Comment: Thank you so much, these changes made it work! E: For anybody else possibly interested: remember to add exclamation marks (!) after `exe 'normal` to avoid loops

Answer (score 1):

Your example could be solved without changing the `ge` motion, by using the `f` and `t` operators:

- `dTo`
- `dF` (d + F + <space> )

If you still feels that you need to override the default behavior of `ge` you shoul check [Ingo Karkat's plugin, CountJump : Create custom motions and text objects via repeated jumps](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5fid=3130):

```
DESCRIPTION
Though it is not difficult to write a custom movement (basically a :map
that executes some kind of search or jump) and a custom text-object (an
:omap that selects a range of text), this is too complex for a novice user
and often repetitive.
```

Comment: I am of course familiar with `F`, I guess this is more a matter of consistency than it is a matter of practicality. I originally started working on this when I used `dge` to correct something where I accidentally had typed 2 spaces instead of 1. Also I have `ge` remapped to one key, so it would be faster too. Anyway, I think this should be doable, and I'm also interested in the solution on theory level. But I'll check out CountJump, thanks.